# apache require user regular expression

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, kerberos

I am using SSL and kerberos authentication in apache and want to pass this variable `%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}s` to `Require user`

```
  SSLVerifyClient require
  SSLVerifyDepth 2
  SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  SSLUserName SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN
  SSLRequire (%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} in {"krisdigitx","usera"})
  AuthType Kerberos
  AuthName "Kerberos Login"
  KrbMethodNegotiate On
  KrbMethodK5Passwd On
  KrbAuthRealms MYDOMAIN.COM
  Krb5KeyTab /etc/security/keytabs/spnego.service.keytab
  Require user "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}s"+"@MYDOMAIN.com"
  #require valid-user
```

any idea how I can do this? the one above does not work....

Comment: Are there any configuration error messages output with the above and if so what? Does it work as one would expect if the directive SSLRequire is removed? And if no errors, what happens with the SSLRequire directive in place as you have it?

Comment: I see. It is the "Require user" line in question. Ignore my previous questions.